# runtime error sigsegv on my code

Tags: c++, runtime

I am new to coding. When I am submitting my code in codecheff its giving "Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)". I Don't know what's the problem please help. Thanks in advance.
  I am new to coding. When I am submitting my code in codecheff its giving "Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)". I Don't know what's the problem please help. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,m,k,i,l,j,a[100000][100000],r,c,s,d;

cin >> n >> m >> k;
cout<<endl;

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
    {
    cin>>a[i][j];
    cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

 for(l=1;l<=k;l++)
{
    cin >> r >> c >> s >> d;

for(i=r;i<=r+s-1;i++)
{
    for(j=c;j<=c+s-1;j++)
    {
        a[i][j]=a[i][j]+d;
    }
}
} 

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
    {
    cout<<a[i][j];
    cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Total array size can be as large as 10^5 = 10,000 is the maximum.
So `int a[100][100]` is the best you can get.

Moreover, You should use `vector<int>` instead of 2-dimentional array. It has more benefits, its easy to use, and has the `[]` operator.

In addition, i'm not sure what is the purpose of the program, therefore i'm not able to optimize your code and make it more elegant. If you'll be able to explain it better, I might have an idea to make it better.